# What is the condition for resistance in the branch to be parallel

Tags: electric-circuits, electrical-resistance

What if the incoming current at one node not equal to the other, does the resistance in branch still parallel.

[image: Circuit diagram]
Eg: In the above circuit diagram how is 17.5 Ω resistor parallel with 5Ω and 2.5Ω resistor?

Comment: The question doesn't make sense. In an electrical circuit there must be some nodes at which the current flow would be equal. Between any two of these such nodes there can be multiple branches with different current flows in each branch.

Comment: A diagram of the circuit you're asking about would make your question much more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The currents will be the same.

Using Kirchoff's current law, the total current going out of any node or any closed contour is 0.

Suppose you have two resistances connected in parallel between nodes A and B. Draw a circle around the parallel resistances. The total current going out of the circle is 0. So outgoing current at A + outgoing current at B = 0. In other words outgoing current at A = incoming current at B.

Or you can do kirchoff's law separately at nodes A and B. Either way, the outgoing current =incoming current.

EDIT: Don't know if I misunderstood the question. But when we say resistances in parallel, we mean all the resistors are connected at one end and the other. So the incoming and outgoing currents have to be the same.